# IGNITE Cache Error

Tags: java, spring, caching, ignite

We are using Apache Ignite for caching and during testing i came accross this error

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cache has been closed or destroyed

We have a Spring Restful client with IGNITE embedded inside. Calls come to update and remove from cache.

The Steps that happened are as follow

1. One instance of Ignite server running.
2. one instance of Restful client running on different server with
   Ignite Embedded.
3. Killed the Ignite server instance, client still running
4. Ignite server restarted.
5. Any attempt by client to put a value in the cache leads to above
   exception.
6. If Client is restarted everything works as normal

Can some one throw some insight as in why this is happening. Do i have to handle that event of all nodes leaving and manually evict cache or something.

Any help is appeciated

Answer (score 3):

In case all servers go down, client rejoins with a new ID (just like if you restart it manually). In this case all existing cache instances are closed and you have to get new ones (use `Ignite.cache(...)` method).

There is a ticket to improve this behavior: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-2766

Comment: Can't ignite.getOrCreateCache(cfg); help here

Comment: Yha i am trying to use above method but is using the same cache name as what i was using before the server went down. I am using a spring caching on client side. is it a stale instance at the client that causes the issue?. is there any way to resolve it without restarting the client?.

Comment: In case of Spring caching there is no workaround except restarting the client. This will be fixed in the next release: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-2765

Answer (score 1):

We also ran into this problem and we have a work-around. We implemented our own version of SpringCacheManager (ReconnectSafeSpringCacheManager) that wraps the cache objects in reconnect-safe cache proxy objects (ReconnectSafeCacheProxy).

When an `IllegalStateException` is caught by one of the cache proxies, we tell our cache manager to drop that cache (remove it from the internal `caches` map) and then we call `ReconnectSafeSpringCacheManager.getCache(<cacheName>)` which recreates the Ignite cache instance. The proxy replaces its cache reference with the new Ignite cache and then the operation that caused the exception is retried.

Our approach required us to place our cache manager code in the `org.apache.ignite.cache.spring` package as there are references to non-public API:s in SpringCacheManager, which isn't the cleanest approach but it seems to work and we plan to remove the work-around when [IGNITE-2786](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-2786) is resolved.